# What is a "unit of a zero-divisor" in a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The following exercise is from Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*:

> Show that every nonzero element of ${\bf Z}_n$ is **a unit of a zero-divisor**.

A [unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29) of a ring is an element which has a multiplicative inverse. A nonzero element $a$ is a commutative ring $R$ is called a [zero-divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor) if there is a nonzero element in $R$ such that $ab=0$.

Here is my **question**:

> What is a unit of a zero-divisor in this exercise?

**Edit:**

According to the answers, this is a typo.

Comment: I deleted my comment and moved it to an answer, along with a link to a hint (after recalling that you were the author of the related prior question).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should say "unit OR a zero-divisor". The proof follows immediately from your [prior exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/49244/242) and an application of [Bezout's GCD identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity) to deduce that $\rm\ gcd(m,n)=1\ \Rightarrow\ m\ $ is a unit in $\rm\:\mathbb Z/n\:.$

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is stated wrongly. It should be:

> Show that every nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a $\text{unit or a zero-divisor}$.

**Solution.**  Suppose that $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$. If $\text{gcd}(a, n) = 1$, then we know that $a$ is a unit. Suppose that $\gcd(a, n) = d > 1$. Then $a(n/d)= (a/d)n = 0$, so $a$ is a zero-divisor.

Comment: Why does gcd$(a,n)=1$ imply $a$ is a unit? Are you using the property of the congruence equation $ax\equiv b\pmod{n}$ that it has a unique solution  (mod n) when gcd$(a,n)=1$?

Comment: @Jack Hint: [Bezout's identity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity)

Comment: @Bill: Hmm, Bezout's identity is more natural to find the inverse. I was thinking about the solution of the congruence equation $ax\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, which finally reduces to the issue of the identity you mentioned:)

Comment: @Jack. Indeed. Note that Chandru's final sentence is the same as the [hint](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49244/zero-divisors-of-bf-z-n/49281#49281) I gave to your prior question.